# Посоветуйте IDE для Rust

Tags: ide, rust

Посоветуйте хорошее Ide gui для языка программирования Rust.

Желательно полегче и под Linux.

Comment: Итог разработки почти месяц на расте. Visual Studio Code отлично подошла + веб доки.

Comment: Время прошло для Visual Studio Code:)) Использую Geany!

Comment: Visual Studio Code!:)

Comment: Досихпор использую Visual Studio Code (VSCode), появилось долгожданное автодополнение, хотябы в `trait` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Раз выбор падает именно на графическую IDE, то пропустим популярные **vim/emacs** и рассмотрим поддержку для популярных графических интегрированных сред разработки:

1. Поддержка для [Atom](https://github.com/zargony/atom-language-rust).
2. Среда разработки [RustDT](https://github.com/RustDT/RustDT), основанная на Eclipse.
3. [IntelliJ Rust](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust).
4. [SolidOak](https://github.com/oakes/SolidOak) IDE. Небольшая среда разработки, написанная на Rust.
5. Поддержка Rust для [VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kalitaalexey.vscode-rust). Расширение поддерживает [RLS](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls).
6. Поддержка [Sublime Text 3](https://github.com/rust-lang/sublime-rust).

---

P.S. Лично я предпочитаю 5ый вариант для больших проектов, а правки и "маленькие" программы делаю с помощью vim.

Comment: Использовал Visual Studio. Мне показалось что она слепа, не видит функций в сторонних библиотеках, но в ней отличная система проверки на ошибки(правда поджирает немного cpu). Пока остановился на IDEA, в ней все идеально за исключением проверки ошибок, думаю попробовать SolidOak  возможно сойдет.

Answer (score 2):

- Немного устаревшая статья на русском про настройку различных [IDE для Rust](https://rustycrate.ru/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0/2015/12/04/ide-for-rust.html)
- Свежая информация на английском про **VS Code** и **RLS**: [What the RLS can do](http://www.ncameron.org/blog/what-the-rls-can-do/)

---

Сам использую **Sublime Text 3** с расширением [Rust Enhanced](https://github.com/rust-lang/sublime-rust#rust-enhanced).

**VS Code** очень неплох и возможностей у него побольше чем у **Sublime**. Но у **VS Code** немного тормознутый интерфейс. Он намного быстрее, чем например **Atom**, но **Sublime** в этом отношении выигрывает.